# How to get django ModelForm to not clean a ManyToManyField before running clean_ for that field?

Tags: django-forms

```
class MyModel(models.Model) :
  people = models.ManyToManyField(User,related_name='people')
  ...

class MyForm(ModelForm) :
  class Meta :
     model = MyModel
     widgets = {'people':TextInput(),}
  def clean_people(self) :
     # turn a comma-separated list of names into a Python list
     return [name0,name1,...]
  def clean(self) :
     # if no other errors, turn list of names into list of Users
```

This doesn't work, because clean_people doesn't get called before field.clean gets called, where field is an instance of ModelMultipleChoiceField, which checks for a Python list or tuple and so raises a ValidationError and skips clean_people.
Is there a reason why the order of calls is the way it is, and is there some standard provision for avoiding this problem? I could set field.clean to lambda x:x in each instance of MyForm, but that seems really ugly. Is perhaps the right thing to do to explicitly define the people field in MyForm as a CharField ?

Answer (score 0):

why don't you [override clean](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-clean-method)'s behaviour?

```
class MyForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        widgets = {'people':TextInput(),}

    def clean_people(self):
        # turn a comma-separated list of names into a Python list
        return [name0,name1,...]

    # override below!
    def clean(self):
        super(MyForm, self).clean()
        # do stuff you need, eg: call clean_people(self)
        return self.cleaned_data
```

I'm not sure I understood your problem 100%, but just by defining clean_people() before clean() doesn't mean that's going to be called before, or even called at all.

Comment: The form's clean routine is called after clean_people, except that the model's clean for the field is called first, and it's not happy with a string, so doesn't ever call clean_people.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the right? thing is to define the people field in the form, overriding the model's idea of that field

```
class MyModel(models.Model) :
  people = models.ManyToManyField(User,related_name='people')
  ...

class MyForm(ModelForm):
    people = CharField(...)

    class Meta :
       model = MyModel

    def clean_people(self) :
       # turn a comma-separated list of names into a Python list
       return [name0,name1,...]

    def clean(self) :
       # if no other errors, turn list of names into list of Users
```